# MySQL issue - startup

Tags: mysql, percona

I have Percona Server 5.6 running in linux platform.. recently I faced an issue where mysql instance was continuously restarting for no reason.. mysql logs had this error:

```
[ERROR] InnoDB: File ./TestBAMC/s_snippet.ibd: 'Linux aio' returned OS error 0. Cannot continue operation
```

Instance has binary logging enabled and has a master-slave configured. This issue is with the master. Does the above error cause the instance to reboot continuously?

Answer (score 1):

Oracle say: This is most probably due to table corruption. See the error number is 0, which indicates success, not actual error. So, this means that read from file was successful and OS returned 0, but actual read data length is different from expected data length. This is unlikely to be a problem on MySQL, but most likely to be a problem on OS including file system.

InnoDB writes data to data file per page. So, size of data file is always multiple of page size. In general, writes against a file is atomic. So, data file will never be non-multiple of page size, if OS works properly. If it's not multiple of page size, InnoDB will read incomplete page at the end of data file, then it results in this error.

Recommended solutions are:
Take following actions to mend or prevent this problem:

Run fsck and check if the file system is flawless.
Replace suspicious disk.
Ensure that the filesystem is transactional. (such as NTFS and ext4)
Check if journaling setting of filesystem is fine.
Change block size of filesystem to same as InnoDB page size (16KB by default)
Upgrade OS to the latest version.

Comment: Do you have any reference material you could supply to corroborate your statement?

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you are hitting full disk conditions? This bug could be related:

https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=68895

Comment: Have checked disk, it has enough space.

Comment: It may have enough disk space now, but not during the incident? Are you monitoring disk space usage? Maybe a rogue temporary table consumed disk space as well?

Comment: Nope. It is 90% free. I think that is not the issue.